# Wake on LAN the Raspberry Pi 4B

Tags: power-management, raspberrypi, wakeonlan

I ask here although there is a [good thread](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/126/how-do-i-enable-wake-on-lan) because I don't want a facebooq or googre account.

I'd like to understand how I could wake a Pi after shutdown/halt/power-off. Querying the embedded BCM54213PE NIC with `ethtool` reports `d` which means disabled which means supported.

When enabling from latest Raspbian, I get the following error:

```
sudo ethtool -s eth0 wol g
Cannot set new wake-on-lan settings: Unknown error 524
  not setting wol
pi@pi:~ $ echo $?
0
```

I can add the chip is still powered as the activity LED still blinks so the link is maintained and enough supply remains to trigger a reboot by sending a pulse to GLOBAL_EN or equiv GPIO.

The solution in the link above is bad as not real Wake-on-LAN, requires additional 12V supply and is nearly as expensive as the Pi itself. Only good thing, it really cuts the mains to the 5V wallet.

I wonder if there is a way to enable Wake-on-LAN for the embedded NIC. If really not because of Pi's genetics (hardware design) then a dedicated slave NIC as wiz5500+PIC is the solution. I reached to do it with an old 82558B PCI NIC and some discrete components, unfortunately it draws too much power (1,5W).

Comment: You haven't mentioned your OS/release and there isn't anything on-topic that I see so far (this isn't https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/)   https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Thank you @guiverc for pointing this lack of info as the issue may be software only. OP updated (Raspbian Buster up to date). I'd consider using Ubuntu if it provided WoL on RPi. Sorry for posting here, I only have a Launchpad account.

Comment: I just allowed myself as I know Ubuntu's heart is Debian.

Answer (score 1):

Wake-on-LAN support is implemented on the *motherboard* **and** *network interface*. WoL is an hardware feature that is **not implemented** on the Raspberry PI boards.
Same thing with USB: no wake up supported

Out-Of-The-Box Pi4 cannot be started by WOL
But you can add some third party hardware for power management that implement WoL.

Comment: Please elaborate. RPi's NIC supports WoL. Why can't/don't RPi set the NIC's registers to WoL mode late on shutdown if instructed to ? We yet have all the required HW, even the power supply.

Comment: @useful: edited/done